# Drupal to Wordpress migration - Keeping the theme same

Tags: wordpress, drupal-7, migration, wordpress-theming

I have a Drupal site and I've have made a decision to migrate it to Wordpress. I want to keep the same design/theme in my new WP site.

I'm wondering what part of current Drupal theme can be used in the new WP theme. Can the HTML/CSS, JS be re-used? If yes, the how?

I don't have any experience with theming so I am curious to know this.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you couldn't do that the css and js should work fine with no modification at all. You will need to do a lot of work on the html first you will have to remove the php or template tags that drupal uses (Not sure how it does it's templates). Then what I suggest you do is take a look at another wordpress theme and replicate the structure and theme files. Take the html from you drupal theme and add it to the wordpress pages style it how you like, now you will need to do some research on how to get what you need out of wordpress this is often done with php tags so your theme files for wordpress will need to be `.php` it is best to have a header and footer php that you can include all you links to the css and javascript. Hope this helps comment bellow if you need more help.

Comment: Is there a blog or document with the detailed steps of the approach you shared?
I have been trying to find one but haven't got a proper solution for this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply not all of the steps I mentioned are included but getting the template working in WordPress you can take a look at the WordPress theme documentation it contains loads of code snippets